# Not able to use bulbs to program Titan GraphDB/Rexster

Tags: python, database, titan, bulbs, rexster

I have Titan (with embedded cassandra running on my system).

```
cd titan-cassandra-0.3.1
bin/titan.sh config/titan-server-rexster.xml config/titan-server-cassandra.properties
```

I have rexster server running

```
cd rexster-console-2.3.0
bin/rexster-console.sh
```

I am able to create a graph from the rexter shell using Gremlin queries.

```
 g = rexster.getGraph("graph")
 v1 = g.addVertex([name:"s1"])
 v2 = g.addVertex([name:"s2"])
 e1 = g.addEdge(v1, v2, "likes")
```

I have installed bulbs on my system as follows.

```
sudo apt-get install python2.7-dev
sudo apt-get install libyaml-dev

sudo pip install  https://github.com/espeed/bulbs/tarball/master
```

If I try the following from ipython on my machine

```
In [1]: from bulbs.rexster import Graph

In [2]: g = Graph()
```

I get the following error.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
LookupError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
/home/karthik/Projects/ryu_extras/<ipython-input-2-eb1ac0314e67> in <module>()
----> 1 g = Graph()

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bulbs/rexster/graph.pyc in __init__(self, config)
     54 
     55     def __init__(self, config=None):
---> 56         super(Graph, self).__init__(config)
     57 
     58         # Rexster supports Gremlin


/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bulbs/base/graph.pyc in __init__(self, config)
     56         self.factory = Factory(self.client)
     57 
---> 58         self.vertices = self.build_proxy(Vertex)
     59         self.edges = self.build_proxy(Edge)
     60 

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bulbs/base/graph.pyc in build_proxy(self, element_class, index_class)
    122         if not index_class:
    123             index_class = self.default_index
--> 124         return self.factory.build_element_proxy(element_class, index_class)
    125 
    126     def load_graphml(self, uri):

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bulbs/factory.pyc in build_element_proxy(self, element_class, index_class, index_name)
     17         proxy_class = element_class.get_proxy_class()
     18         element_proxy = proxy_class(element_class, self.client)
---> 19         primary_index = self.get_index(element_class,index_class,index_name)
     20         element_proxy.index = primary_index
     21         return element_proxy

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bulbs/factory.pyc in get_index(self, element_class, index_class, index_name)
     25             index_name = element_class.get_index_name(self.client.config)
     26         index_proxy = self.build_index_proxy(element_class, index_class)
---> 27         index = index_proxy.get_or_create(index_name)
     28         return index
     29 

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bulbs/rexster/index.pyc in get_or_create(self, index_name, index_params)
     78 
     79         """ 
---> 80         resp = self.client.get_or_create_vertex_index(index_name, index_params)
     81         index = self.index_class(self.client,resp.results)
     82         self.client.registry.add_index(index_name, index)

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bulbs/rexster/client.pyc in get_or_create_vertex_index(self, index_name, index_params)
    666         script = self.scripts.get('get_or_create_vertex_index')
    667         params = dict(index_name=index_name, index_params=index_params)
--> 668         resp = self.gremlin(script, params)
    669         #assert "MANUAL" in resp.content['results'][0]

    670         result = {'name': index_name, 'type': 'manual', 'class': 'vertex'}

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bulbs/rexster/client.pyc in gremlin(self, script, params, load)
    354         if self.config.server_scripts is True:
    355             params["load"] = load or [self.scripts.default_namespace]
--> 356         return self.request.post(gremlin_path, params)
    357 
    358 

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bulbs/rest.pyc in post(self, path, params)
    129 
    130         """
--> 131         return self.request(POST, path, params)
    132 
    133     def delete(self, path, params=None):

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bulbs/rest.pyc in request(self, method, path, params)
    184         http_resp = self.http.request(uri, method, body, headers)
    185 
--> 186         return self.response_class(http_resp, self.config)
    187 
    188 

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bulbs/rexster/client.pyc in __init__(self, response, config)
    196     def __init__(self, response, config):
    197         self.config = config
--> 198         self.handle_response(response)
    199         self.headers = self.get_headers(response)
    200         self.content = self.get_content(response)

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bulbs/rexster/client.pyc in handle_response(self, http_resp)
    220         headers, content = http_resp
    221         response_handler = RESPONSE_HANDLERS.get(headers.status)
--> 222         response_handler(http_resp)
    223 
    224     def get_headers(self,response):

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bulbs/rest.pyc in not_found(http_resp)
     37 
     38 def not_found(http_resp):
---> 39     raise LookupError(http_resp)
     40     #return None

     41 

LookupError: ({'status': '404', 'transfer-encoding': 'chunked', 'server': 'grizzly/2.2.16', 'date': 'Sat, 10 May 2014 06:22:49 GMT', 'access-control-allow-origin': '*', 'content-type': 'application/json'}, '{"message":"Graph [emptygraph] could not be found"}')
```

What does these mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Titan has its own module...

```
>>> from bulbs.titan import Graph
>>> g = Graph()
```